# How to identify if an object is a Collection or Dictionary?

Tags: vba, collections

I have a nested tree of nodes that are either `Dictionaries` or `Collections` (I don't have control over this structure - it is given to me). How can I seperate `Dictionary` nodes from `Collections`?

I observe there exists an `IsArray()` function, but no `IsCollection` or `IsDict()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Sub TestingType()
    Dim col As New Collection
    Dim dic As New Scripting.Dictionary

    Debug.Print TypeName(col)   'Collection
    Debug.Print TypeName(dic)   'Dictionary

End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent - didn't know about `TypeName`

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
If TypeOf YourObjectVariable Is Dictionary Then
    ' ...
ElseIf TypeOf YourObjectVariable Is Collection Then
    ' ...
Else
    ' Handle empty/other types here.
End If
```

You could use something like this to control the flow of execution in your code, or make your own IsCollection() and IsDictionary() functions.